# Ford 2000 wind star , tool slid into hallow area above front driver side wheel

Tags: ford, windstar

How do i open the area up to retrieve the tool

it slid down into it through the opening under the drivers side windshield wiper then into this hallow area above the wheel

Comment: If it's where I'm thinking, you either need to take the cowl apart ... or if the other place, you'll need to pull the fender off of that side. Not a lot of fun either way.

Answer (score 1):

If it's where I'm thinking, you either need to take the cowl apart ... or if the other place, you'll need to pull the fender off of that side. Not a lot of fun either way. If the tool is made of steel, you may be able to get an extendable magnet and fish it out. Not a perfect method, but might save a lot of trouble.